# .htaccess Warning, RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored

Tags: php, .htaccess

We are getting this error in .htaccess file "RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored". We have written this rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.* loadpage.php [QSA,L]
```

What can we do for remove this warning.

Comment: Is that all of your rules or do you have more rules in the .htaccess. Also are you on a shared hosting? I've heard of others getting messages from other sites that is not related to yours.

Comment: Hi Panama, No we are not using shared hosting.my whole file content is.                                                                                              <filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US
</filesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*\.* loadpage.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Always post your **REAL** rules when opening a question. We can't help you if you don't put the **exact** rules because there is no way to tell what's actually wrong. In your question you left out the fact that you are using `NC` on the condition. That is exactly your problem which is what it's telling you. You can not use `NC` flag with those options. You need to remove the `NC` flag from those rules.

```
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$"> 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
DefaultLanguage en-US 
</filesMatch> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.*\.* loadpage.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Change your rules to this.

```
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$"> 
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
DefaultLanguage en-US 
</filesMatch> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*\.* loadpage.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi Panama, This is my all REAL rules. I also tried this what your answered. But still getting same warning.